Does RSC/Next.js guarantee you receive formData in server action on a form submission?
I am reading through the new Next.js docs, trying to learn more about React Server Components and server actions. In the validation section they show an example of using Zod to validate the formData values. However, I am wondering if it is also necessary to check that what we receive are formData in the first place?
For example, in this server action:
export default async function createUser(formData: FormData) {
  const validatedFields = schema.safeParse({
    email: formData.get('email'),
  })
  // ...
}

can client crash the server through manipulating the request by replacing the form data with something else? And if so, what would be a good way to validate the form data? Something like?:
export default async function createUser(formData: FormData) {
  if (!(formData instanceof FormData)) return 'Invalid request'

  const validatedFields = schema.safeParse({
    email: formData.get('email'),
  })
  // ...
}


There are no guarantees in distributed systems - and rule #1 is never trust the client - so it's always appropriate to validate incoming data like this.

"can client crash the server through manipulating the request by replacing the form data with something else?" - Oooooh yes. Simply not providing a value for a given field might mean the property is null or undefined in server-side JS code, which will cause server code to fail with a null-reference-exception unless it either validates for unexpected empty members or its using some special (in-proc) model-binding library provides its own guarantees.

Thanks. Obviously, anything can come from the client, so my question was aimed specifically at Next.JS/RSC if there is already some logic/internal validation in the libraries that would limit how much we need to do ourselves.
